# Firebase admin java SDK - Fetching change data instead of all data at that time when an event occurs

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using below firebase-admin version 6.5.0

My db structure is as below

```
-DB  
  -chat  
     -branches  
      - 1  
      - 2  
        - users  
        - message
         -1  
          - content : "hi",  
          - messageType : "text"  
         -2
          - content : "hello",
          - messageType : "text"
      - 3
```

In above structure I am listening to child at branches level as below

```
ref.child("chat").child("branches").addValueEventListener()
```

Whenever some new message is added, I am receiving all data below branches instead of only changed branch. i.e. I am getting 1,2,3 all branches data in above data structure.

Is there any way to only get changed child data?

.i.e. chat - branches - 2 - message - content (if content gets changed).

---

editing according to below response

If I am listening to change done at message 2 using 
**ref.child("chat").child("branches").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener())**

for branches child its giving only 2 but message children its giving all messages. How to get only changed message child details.

I am trying to query like this ***chat.branches.$branchid.message.$messageid***

Answer (score 2):

A `ValueEventListener` always gets a snapshot of the entire location you attach it to.

If you'd like to get a snapshot of the specific child, you should use a `ChildEventListener`.

```
ref.child("chat").child("branches").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getKey()+" was added after "+previousChildKey);
  }
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getKey()+" was changed");
  }
  ...
```

When you first attach this listener, the `onChildAdded` method will be called for each branch. After that, if you make a change to a single branch, the `onChildChanged` method will be called for just that branch.

Comment: Hi Frank 
Thanks for responding. Is there a way to get directly the changed child instead of me looping through the "branches" children?
when I used **childEventListener** am getting child below branches but if data is something like this
*-DB  
  -chat  
     -branches  
      - 1  
      - 2  
        - users  
        - message-1 
          - content : "hi",  
        - message-2
         - content : "hello",  
      - 3*
Some new message-3 got added or message-2 got changed then how can I fetch only that message-2 details instead of getting all children details below branches

Comment: A `ChildEventListener` fires for the immediately child that was changed. There is no listener that fires for specific grandchild nodes, or even further down the tree. If you need to get notified of that level, create a data structure that allows this. So if you want to be notified of messages (no matter what chat/branch they're in), create a list of messages (regardless of the chat/branch they're in), and attach a `ChildEventListener` to that.

Comment: How is parallelism handled when we use ChildEventListener? Can we have multiple listeners running and handling message changes among them in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  var changedPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log("The updated post title is " + changedPost.title);
});
```

For more information you can **[click](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-changed)** Here